# Does offsides in NFHS soccer overrule handing in the penalty box?

Tags: football

*A1 is in an offside position* at the moment A2 takes a shot on goal. After that, B3 (not the goalkeeper) deliberately handles the ball on the goalline between the goal posts. The ball goes to A1, who scores a goal.

Doesn't the offside overrule anything else that occurs after the shot has been taken?

Comment: Was A1 interfering with play _at the time the shot was taken_?

Comment: what's the positional relationship between A1 and B3 at the time the shot was taken?

Comment: Just to clarify: A1 is forward (closer to goal) than B3, and A2 shoots at goal, deflected by the hand of B3.  A1 then plays the rebound and scores?  As Philip asked, was A1 near B3 and/or the shot when taken, or not near to the play when the shot was taken?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the goalkeeper? Presumably well out of his goal since if A1 is in an offside position, then B3 is the only player between A1 and the goal.

Now let's say it had been the goalkeeper, standing on the goal line, who had saved the shot with his hand and it had fallen to the player in an offside position - then the player A1 would still have been offside. A goalkeeper saving a shot cannot thereby play an attacker onside, who was offside when the shot was taken.

So I don't really see why it should be any different where any other player does the same thing. Therefore I believe the goal should be disallowed as offside. (It would be no different to the position if B3 had saved the shot with any other part of his body.)

However the referee should award a penalty and take disciplinary action against the player who saved with his hand - in the English leagues almost certainly a red card for stopping an otherwise certain goal.

Comment: +1 A1 being offside offsets nothing happening prior to A1 scoring.